# Application remnants

Tags: printing

I recently installed had to re-install Repetier Host onto my computer, cause during the download to the latest version, i had constant issues with it freezing my entire computer, to the point of me having to hit restart to fix the issue.

However, Now it seems as though I have a phantom application. For whatever reason, when I look in my applications, I have the words Repetier-Host floating underneath a blank icon. Obviously it didn't show up in the snap store, since Repetier can't be downloaded from there, but it was worth a shot. Then, I tried to locate that specific file in the computer, but the locate command couldn't find it. Finally, I just decided to use **sudo apt purge Repetier***, and figured it would be worth just re-installing it again, but even after that, it was still there.

Poking around on the Official forums, I found a dude who had a similar issue with KeePass. He solved it by looking in **~/.local/share/applications,** and removing the appropriate fil, but when i looked there, nothing was labeled with repetier.

The worst part of it all, is that even after the multiple re-downloads, I still get the issue where Repetier freezes the whole computer. I even asked in their forums about it, and they have no clue what's going on.

Is there anything that I'm missing, like a really obvious place to look in order to remove it? i just wanna be able to use my 3d printer again man.

Comment: Where did the comment about the printer come from in the last line? There is noting in the question about a printer not working.

Comment: Most basic starting point in my view is what Ubuntu product/release; also packages can be in different formats so some package tools (eg. `apt`) aren't correct, and you provide many details on things you've done, but without specifics as to the actual package type, your OS/release etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You start out saying you reinstalled an app, then complain that it exists on your system. Please edit for clarity, and give technical details, not vague descriptions.

Comment: Sorry about the question being a bit unclear, It's my first time using these forums, so I don't know everything that I need to include. I'll start one question at a time.                              For the last line about the print, you can just disregard that completely.                                      For the re-installing the app question, I had the app installed beforehand, but in order to update Repetier, they have an odd way of releasing them, where you have to re-install the entire application, and I think remnants of the older build is stuck

Comment: Ran out of space, but I'm also using 22.04.2 of Ubuntu, and I can attach a screenshot of what exactly my issue is if you want it? Sorry for being vague and confusing.

Comment: Did you previously use the *AppImage* file from their site?